# To mold the shape into the shape you (want / want it /wanted)

Tags: phrase-choice

In [this](https://youtu.be/-3oCdNIeU_8?t=118) video, the girl said:

> And you can click and drag on these points to mold the shape into the shape you *want it*.

This is the sentence shows in the CC. I think it should be *want it (to be)* or *wanted*. Is the sentence shows in the CC grammatically right? If it is, please help me distinguish the different meanings of the 3 sentences below.

1. to mold the shape into the shape you *want it*.
2. to mold the shape into the shape you *wanted*.
3. to mold the shape into the shape you *want*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"want it" on its own does not seem to be correct. It should be "want it to be" when talking about a current plan or "wanted" when talking about a previous plan.

Answer (score 1):

I clearly hear "*...into the shape you want **it***".

In unprepared speech, such as live commentary in a YouTube video like this, it is natural, and means, "*...into the shape you want it **to be***."

If it had been properly scripted, she would have said, "*... into the shape you **want***" or "*... into the shape you **want it to be**.*"

"**...wanted ...**" doesn't make sense because people are making the shape they want now, not a shape they chose earler.